# Use Jquery in AngularJs controller folder can't be load (GET error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I got a html view `homeView.html` there :

```
<ul id="brand">
<li>
    <img src="../../resources/images/11.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Buy Rice Products Are Now On Line With Us</h3>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="../../resources/images/22.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Whole Spices Products Are Now On Line With Us</h3>
    </div>
</li>

<li>
    <img src="../../resources/images/44.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Whole Spices Products Are Now On Line With Us</h3>
    </div>
</li>
```

And I got a `JQuery` code to work with which is in my controller:

```
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/productList')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.products = response.data;
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data)
        })

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#brand').skdslider({ 'delay': 5000, 'animationSpeed': 2000, 'showNextPrev': true, 'showPlayButton': true, 'autoSlide': true, 'animationType': 'fading' });

        jQuery('#responsive').change(function () {
            $('#responsive_wrapper').width(jQuery(this).val());
        });

    });
}]);
```

Actually, I got a `index.html` file which load every html views and scripts/css/jquery etc.. My `homeView.html` is load like this in this file :

```
<div ng-include="'components/views/shared/headerView.html'"></div>
<div ng-view></div>

  <div ng-include="'components/views/shared/footerView.html'"></div>

  <script src="resources/bower/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/bower/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="components/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/minicart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/skdslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

And when I am loading my homepage, the jQuery code is executed but I got this in my console :

> GET http://localhost:5000/resources/images/ 404 (Not Found)

From `jquery.min`

But I load the script of jquery before all those code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I guess this issue is due to priority of script loaded.. If an expert could help me please..

Comment: This is due to you don't have `images` folder on your server. Add this folder with all images you are using.

Comment: Make sure `../../resources/images/44.jpg` refer to the correct location relative to the `index.html`

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, Do I have to duplicate this folder on my server ? because I already got one on Client side (and my images are loaded from there)

Comment: @Thusitha, yep the path is linked with the image, I could access it by ctrl + click on the path. And images are correctly load on my page, I just got the error in my console..

Comment: Load `<script src="resources/js/skdslider.min.js"></script>` before angular.js but after `jquery`

Comment: @Thusitha, Nope, same problem :/

Comment: @Cupkek05 add complete path of `images` folder in html and check.

Comment: I should precise that if I remove the jQuery code from my controller, It works without this error, In my opinion, the problem should be there, should I load the jQuery in controller... I am not sure

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, Ok I changed path with `/Client/app/ressources/images/11.jpg` images are correctly load again but this time I got more errors :  `GET http://localhost:5000/Client/app/resources/images/11.jpg 404 (Not Found)` for the 3 files and for the folder

Comment: @Cupkek05 could you add previous path again ?? Complete path D:/ this one

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, `D:/wamp64/www/Foodtastic/Client/app/resources/images/11.jpg` But images are not loaded with this path

Comment: @Cupkek05 is this path accessible to you ?? `http://localhost:5000/Foodtastic/Client/app/resources/images/11.jpg`

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, Nope it is no

Comment: @Cupkek05 where are actual images are stored then ??

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, That's why I am not understanding... Images are stored there... in this path, but if I am using this path I can't access images...

Comment: @Cupkek05 ok. and is `D:/wamp64/www/Foodtastic/Client/app/resources/images/11.jpg` this path is accessible using browser ??

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, yes it is, but you can't use that path because browser dont allow to access on local ressources right ?

Comment: @Cupkek05 try `<img src="resources/images/11.jpg" alt="" />` this path ??

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, I can't acess to image from code, but images are correctly load on page ... hhm...And still got the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155515/discussion-between-cupkek05-and-kaustubh-khare).